# How to forget a wireless network in android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, android-internet, android-wireless

I am working on an app which wifi , where user will be asked to enter password for the scanned network he selects, if user enters a correct password, it connects and works well. But when user enters wrong password, a new network is added with that name, and will be failing to authenticate cos of wrong password, and it will be having authentication problem status.

Now if user tries to again scan and select the same network, and enters correct password, it fails to connect even though password now is correct and will have disabled status, since the previous connection is still showing that authentication problem status.

How to solve this problem?
Is there any way to forget all networks using ConnectivityManager or wifimanager? Or any other solution?

Comment: Go through this link for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/51081719/7094064

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `WifiManager` source code, has this method:

```
/*
 * Delete the network in the supplicant config.
 *
 * This function is used instead of a sequence of removeNetwork()
 * and saveConfiguration().
 *
 * @param config the set of variables that describe the configuration,
 *            contained in a {@link WifiConfiguration} object.
 * @hide
 */

public void forgetNetwork(int netId) {
    if (netId < 0) {
        return;
    }
    mAsyncChannel.sendMessage(CMD_FORGET_NETWORK, netId);
}
```

But this method is `@hide`, so we can't use it. But according to this comment:

> This function is used instead of a sequence of `removeNetwork()` and
>   `saveConfiguration()`

You can try to use: `removeNetwork()` and `saveConfiguration()` instead.

Answer (score 25):

Yes, `removeNetwork()` works. I used this to remove all networks.

```
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
    wifiManager.removeNetwork(i.networkId);
    //wifiManager.saveConfiguration();  
}
```

**wifiManager.saveConfiguration()**

This method was deprecated in API level 26. There is no need to call
this method - addNetwork(WifiConfiguration),
updateNetwork(WifiConfiguration) and removeNetwork(int) already persist
the configurations automatically.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#saveConfiguration()

Comment: wifiManager.saveConfiguration();   is deprecated what is the alternative one to use

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`removeNetwork()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#removeNetwork%28int%29) method to remove the redundant network connections(though I have a doubt if they will have the same `netId`) and then add the connection freshly to avoid the problem you are having.

Comment: removeNetwork() solved the problem! while, setting up config, I read the networkID to a variable, so that when the network fails to connect, I removed it using same id in  `removeNetwork()` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
```

is deprectated in Android M. No longer need to call saveConfiguration as removeNetwork(int) already persist the configurations automatically.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#saveConfiguration()

Answer (score 0):

By doing this it is possible to get the list of networks configured in a list, then immediately perform the deletion and save.

```javaScript
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
            wifiManager.removeNetwork(i.networkId);
            wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need the especific permission.

```
final int numOpenNetworksKept = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17
                ? Settings.Secure.getInt(resolver, Settings.Global.WIFI_NUM_OPEN_NETWORKS_KEPT, 10)
                : Settings.Secure.getInt(resolver, Settings.Secure.WIFI_NUM_OPEN_NETWORKS_KEPT, 10);
```