# Forgot network not working in Android Marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am using below code to remove or forgot configure Wi-Fi network:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.removeNetwork(networkID);
```

but its not working in os 6.0, please suggest?

Comment: Add permission in Android manifest and as well check run time permission for network state

Comment: Should i add this permission in runtime android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE?

Comment: or this one android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE or both?

Comment: Add both permission !!

Comment: No, not work, I am using both permissions and its protection level is normal so I think no need to add this in runtime, and its already added in manifest

Comment: Though if it is added but in Marshmallow you have to check run time permission

Comment: Yes I have checked it, its status is showing 0 i.e granted, so both permissions are already there, still I am not able to forgot network

Comment: You have remove the network ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use like this:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
       int networkId = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
       wifiManager.removeNetwork(networkId);
       wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
```

Hope it will helps you  !!

Comment: Any exception or something else ?

Comment: Nothing no exception, disableNetwork function is working fine but removeNetwork doesn't remove the configure network

Comment: Please have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756690/android-m-unable-to-remove-wi-fi-ap-programmatically

Comment: Thanks for help, this is the exact problem wifi was created by me in wifi settings, when I tried to remove the wifi through my app its not working because of WIFI_DEVICE_OWNER_CONFIGS_LOCKDOWN, but wifi created by me in my app I am able to remove that network

Comment: Great !! Happy Coding