# Android - Cant Remove Wifi Network Programatically- The method removeNetwork(int) in the type WifiManager is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java, android, timer, wifi

I'm attempting to remove my wifi network programatically - however I cannot seem to get it to remove/forget the currently connected wifi connection. This should be a pretty simple task - so I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using the following StackOverflow post as an example:

[How to forget a wireless network in android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134383/how-to-forget-a-wireless-network-in-android-programmatically)

```
     public class KillTimer extends Activity {

     @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.killtimer);
       WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
       wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSSID()
       wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetoworkId();
       wifiManager.removeNetwork(wifiConfig.networkId);
       wifiManager.saveConfiguration();

   }}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`removeNetwork()` takes only integer parameters. The `networkSSID` is a string value. That's the cause for the error. I see that you are using SSID which is a string. You have to give the network id which is integer. You can try `getConnectionInfo().getSSID()` and compare with your ssid, if they are same  then you can try getting `getConnectionInfo().getNetoworkId()` which should give the connected network's network id, which you can use to removeNetwork.

Try this:

```
public class KillTimer extends Activity {
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.killtimer);
           WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
           int networkId = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
           wifiManager.removeNetwork(networkId);
           wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
       }}
```

**Latest Updates As Of 10 June 2019**

There are some changes for Wifi Manager in Android 6.0 onwards.

**Any Wi-Fi configuration created by an active Device Owner can no longer be modified or deleted by the user if WIFI_DEVICE_OWNER_CONFIGS_LOCKDOWN is non-zero.**

Active Device Owners have the privilege of editing or removing any Wi-Fi configurations, including those not created by them.

For more details, please refer: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html

Comment: I actually don't need to hard code a specific SSID to be removed - I simply want to remove whichever SSID is currently connected. I updated my source code above (I omitted the section you mentioned creating to compare them - since I want to simply disconnect whichever is connected) Can you take a look and see if my current implementation looks correct to you?

Comment: [I really appreciate your help with this!]

Comment: You have got most of it right. Try the code in the edited response

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar... Thank you sir! (It's working!)

Answer (score 4):

```
private void RemoveWifiNetworks() {

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for (WifiConfiguration i : list) {
        //int networkId = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
        wifiManager.removeNetwork(i.networkId);
        wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
    }

}
```