# Android - Still can't remove Wifi Network Programatically

Tags: java, android, wifimanager

After reading several other questions/answers, I'm still having an issue using wifiManager.removeNetwork to work.

According to:

[Android - Cant Remove Wifi Network Programatically- The method removeNetwork(int) in the type WifiManager is not applicable for the arguments (String)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050122/android-cant-remove-wifi-network-programatically-the-method-removenetworkint)

and

[How to forget a wireless network in android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134383/how-to-forget-a-wireless-network-in-android-programmatically)

...my code should work:

```
WifiManager wifiMAN = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

for (WifiConfiguration wifiCon : wifiMAN.getConfiguredNetworks()) {
    if (wifiCon.SSID.equals( "\""+ targetNetworkName +"\"")) {
        wifiMAN.removeNetwork(wifiCon.networkId)) {
        wifiMAN.saveConfiguration();
        break;
    }
}
```

However, when I test on API 23 it doesn't work. Looking through the code nothing appears depreciated and the code works on API 21. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Go through the following link for details,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51081719/7094064

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is intended behavior. As of Android M apps are not allowed to modify networks that they did not create.

See: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187347 and https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-network

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful!